# How can I make the password work with DellBiosProvider?

Tags: powershell, provider, bios

I have a problem on powershell with the DELLBiosProvider The password does not work?
But when I put a numeric password, it passes without problem.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
[string]$pass2= 'K4P9R1'
$id = $pass2.ToUpper()
Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\IntegratedAudio "Disbled" -Verose -Password $id
Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\Microphone "Disabled" -Verbose -Password $id
Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\InternalSpeaker "Disabled" -Verbose -Password $id
exit 0
```

RESULT:

```
Set-Item : Incorrect password provided!
Au caractère Ligne:6 : 1
+ Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\InternalSpeaker "Disab ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (DellSmbios:\Sys...InternalSpeaker:String) [Set-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SMBIOSWriteFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

But with capital letters, it does not work.
Can you tell me more.

By simplifying the code always the same error.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents> $PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
[string]$pass2= 'K4P9R1'
Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\IntegratedAudio "Disabled" -Verbose -Password $pass2
Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\Microphone "Disabled" -Verbose -Password $pass2
Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\InternalSpeaker "Disabled" -Verbose -Password $pass2
COMMENTAIRES : Performing the operation Set-Item on target "Name: DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\IntegratedAudio Value: Disabled".
COMMENTAIRES : Value being set using PLDM Interface
COMMENTAIRES : Password type 'Admin' (Setup) is set.
Set-Item : Incorrect password provided!
Au caractère Ligne:3 : 1
+ Set-Item –Path DellSmbios:\SystemConfiguration\IntegratedAudio "Disab ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (DellSmbios:\Sys...IntegratedAudio:String) [Set-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SMBIOSWriteFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

Thanks

Comment: Based on your error message and your description of the problem, I am tempted to think that your original `$pass2` contains a lowercase character, which you eliminate by doing `$id = $pass2.ToUpper()`  so when you call that `Set-Item`, it does not match the password that was initially input. That would explain also why an all-numeric password work just as well, because lowercase / uppercase is not relevant for a numeric password.

Comment: Please paste the error as text instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: Hello
At first I did with `-passwordsecure`' it doesn't work.
Then I made a variable `$pass2` only it doesn't work.
then I made it `UPPER` and it doesn't work either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my password problem. It was that the BIOS is in QWERTY all simply.

Thanks